# Ловим клик на изображение в фрейме

Tags: javascript, iframe

Пытаюсь поймать клик на изображении в фрейме. 
Вот так не работает (hidden_pole - id фрейма):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#hidden_pole').contents().find('img').click(function(){
     alert('Works');
  });
});
```

Что не так?

**Обновление**

Определил ошибку, но исправить не могу. Дело в том, что изображение вставляется в фрейм, поэтому на нем не отрабатывает событие. Здесь мне в помощь обработчик live, но он не срабатывает:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#hidden_pole').contents().find('img').live('click', function(){
     alert('Works');
  });
});
```

Comment: Фрейм на том же домене?

Comment: Ну т.е. у меня фрейм редактируемый. Скажет так:
$('#hidden_pole').contents().find('img').attr('src') - я получу ссылку на изображение. А вот событие не срабатывает

Comment: Определил ошибку, но исправить не могу. Дело в том, что изображение вставляется в фрейм, поэтому на нем не отрабатывает событие. Здесь мне в помощь обработчик live, но он не срабатывает:
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#hidden_pole').contents().find('img').live('click', function(){
     alert('Works');
  });
});